# I picked it up off the floor, or I picked it up off of the floor?

Tags: prepositions

I came across the sentence below:

> I dropped my crayon, so I picked it up off of the floor.

Why is the prepostion 'of' used like 'off of the floor'?

In my opinion, it seems like "I picked it up off the floor." is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Off of” is an idiom common in American English speech. In you example, it may be reduced to “off”.